# PHP Upload Multiple File with Optionals(requires 1 of 2 files at least)

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a form that contains 2 files, one it's an `.dae` object, other is an `image`.
The form(it's inside a `JS bootbox dialog`):

```
message:  '<form name="uploadForm" action="Control/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> '
                + '     Nome do objeto:<br />'
                + '     <input name="objectname" type="text"><br />'
                + '     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">'
                + '     Objeto 3D(Formato <b>.dae</b>):<br />'
                + '     <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />'
                + '     Imagem 2D do objeto(Formato <b>.png</b> ou <b>.jpg</b>) (<i>Opcional</i>):'
                + '     <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />'
                + '     Comentário:<br />'
                + '     <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="75"></textarea>'
                + '</form>',
```

In the the form, theres two upload files, the "Objeto 3D"(3d object, `.dae`) and the "Imagem 2D do Objeto"(Image 2d of the object, `.jpg, .png`)
It's necessary to upload **only the object file** , the **image is OPTIONAL**, 'cause if it's not uploaded, there's a standard one in the database.

I tried to make it work creating an boolean $imageUploaded, that is setted in the getFileInputs method, but somehow, it doesn't quite work..

- If I upload **a .dae and an image**, works perfectly
- If I upload wrong file extension, it works perfectly(2 wrongs or 1 at
  a time)
- **But if I upload only a .dae file, it get's me the error that the
  image file extension is wrong...**

Here's my code(it runs on other script)(without the database code, not necessary here)

```
<?php 

    class UploadObject{
        //Control vars
        private $uploadIsOk;
        private $imageUploaded;

        //Input vars
        private $objectName;
        private $objectComment;
        private $uploadDir;
        private $uploadFiles;
        private $tmpFileNames;

        //Messages
        private $successMessage;
        private $errorMessage;


        public function __construct($uploadDir){
            $this->uploadIsOk = TRUE;
            $this->imageUploaded = FALSE;
            $this->successMessage = '';
            $this->errorMessage = '';

            $this->uploadDir = $uploadDir;
        }

        //Methods

        public function main(){
            $this->getTextInputs();
            $this->getFileInputs();

            $this->checkFileExtensions();
            if($this->getUploadIsOk()){
                $this->uploadTheFiles();
                $this->alertMessage($this->getSuccessMessage());
            }else{
                $this->alertMessage($this->getErrorMessage());
            }
        }

        public function uploadTheFiles(){
            $message = '';

            $this->replaceFileNames();

            if( move_uploaded_file( $this->getTmpFileNames()[0], $this->getUploadFiles()[0] ) ){
                $message = $message . "Upload do objeto foi realizado com sucesso;<br>";
                if($this->getImageUploaded()){

                    if( move_uploaded_file( $this->getTmpFileNames()[1], $this->getUploadFiles()[1] ) ){
                        $message = $message . "Upload da imagem do objeto foi realizado com sucesso;";
                    }

                }
                else{
                    $message = $message . "Imagem do objeto não foi enviada;";
                }
                $this->setSuccessMessage($message);
            }

        }

        public function getTextInputs(){
            if($_POST["objectname"] != "")
                $this->setObjectName($_POST["objectname"]);
            else 
                $this->setObjectName("objeto");
            $this->setObjectComment($_POST["comment"]);
        }

        public function getFileInputs(){
            $objectFile = $this->uploadDir . 'objects/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]);
            $imageFile = '';

            if($_FILES["userfile"]["name"][0] != ""){
                $imageFile = $this->uploadDir . 'images/' . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"][1]);
                $this->setImageUploaded(TRUE);
            }

            $uploadFiles = array($objectFile, $imageFile);

            $this->setUploadFiles($uploadFiles);

            $tmpObjectName = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][0];
            if($this->getImageUploaded())
                $tmpImageName = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][1];
            else
                $tmpImageName = "";

            $tmpFileNames = array($tmpObjectName, $tmpImageName);

            $this->setTmpFileNames($tmpFileNames);
        }

        public function checkFileExtensions(){
            $message = '';
            if(pathinfo( $this->getUploadFiles()[0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) != "dae"){
                $this->setUploadIsOk(FALSE);

                $message = $message . 'Erro: Objeto com formato inválido, utilize arquivos .dae;<br>';
            }
            if($this->getImageUploaded()){
                if(pathinfo( $this->getUploadFiles()[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) != "jpg" && pathinfo( $this->getUploadFiles()[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) != "jpeg" && pathinfo( $this->getUploadFiles()[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) != "png"){
                    $this->setUploadIsOk(FALSE);

                    $message = $message . 'Erro: Imagem com formato inválido, utilize arquivos .jpg, .jpeg ou .png;';
                }
            }
            $this->setErrorMessage($message);

        }

        public function replaceFileNames(){
            date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
            $data = date("h-i-sa-") . date("Y-m-d-");

            $fileName = $data . $this->getObjectName();

            $objectExtension = '.' . pathinfo($this->getUploadFiles()[0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $newObjectName = str_replace(basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]), $fileName . $objectExtension, $this->getUploadFiles()[0]);

            $newImageName = '';
            if($this->getImageUploaded()){
                $imageExtension = '.' . pathinfo($this->getUploadFiles()[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $newImageName = str_replace(basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'][1]), $fileName . $imageExtension, $this->getUploadFiles()[1]);
            }

            $uploadFiles = array($newObjectName, $newImageName);

            $this->setUploadFiles($uploadFiles);
        }

        public function alertMessage($message){

            $alertMessage = "<script >bootbox.alert({ message: '";

            $alertMessage = $alertMessage . $message;

            $alertMessage = $alertMessage . "', callback: function(){location.href='../index.php';} })</script>";

            echo $alertMessage;


        }

        //Getters and Setters
        ...
        ?>
```

Anyway, I'm new to PHP, wrote this code by myself to learn a bit, but can't work though this problem...Can someone tell me where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by debugging what you get with **print_r($_FILES);**. Compare what you get when you upload the .dae file alone, and what you get when you upload both the .dae file and the image. Then you add a conditional logic to function uploadTheFiles() to skip trying to upload the image if one is not set.

Comment: if I don't send any file, the comparison $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][1] == "" returns TRUE, so the code should work, making $imageUploaded stay FALSE, and it shouldn't call the part of checkExtensions code that gets an error... it's really weird ;~

Comment: $this->setImageUploaded(TRUE); should be $this->imageUploaded(TRUE);

Comment: like I said , I'm new to PHP, so my setter function(setImageUploaded($imageUploaded){ $this->imageUploaded = $imageUploaded; }) doesn't work? I need to set an value directly on the attribute using $this->attribute(value) ?

Comment: Ah, so you have a setter, I said that because I didn't see it in the code above. Well, it should work, but you could always try to change it directly. Try to debug the setter and see if it works